# Weighted sum of points within unit circle

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Say you have two vectors within the unit circle, $r_1 = [x_1, y_1]$, $r_2 = [x_2, y_2]$. How can I prove that the sum $r_3 = \alpha_1*r_1 + \alpha_2*r_2$ is within the unit circle if $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = 1$ and $\alpha_{1,2} \geq 0$.

First of all, is it correct that the sum should be within the unit circle?

I tried using the sum of squares inequality, saying that the points are vectors originating in origo, but I did not get anywhere with that.

Comment: This theorem is showing convexity of the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

- $|r_1|^2=x_1^2+y_1^2\le 1$
- $|r_2|^2=x_2^2+y_2^2\le 1$
- $r_1\cdot r_2=x_1x_2+y_1y_2\le 1$
- $\alpha_1+\alpha_2=1\implies \alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2+2\alpha_1\alpha_2=1$

and

$$r_3 = \alpha_1\cdot r_1 + \alpha_2\cdot r_2=(\alpha_1\cdot x_1 + \alpha_2\cdot x_2,\alpha_1\cdot y_1 + \alpha_2\cdot y_2)$$

and therefore

$$|r_3|^2=r_{3,x}^2+r_{3,y}^2=(\alpha_1\cdot x_1 + \alpha_2\cdot x_2)^2+(\alpha_1\cdot y_1 + \alpha_2\cdot y_2)^2=$$

$$=\alpha_1^2\cdot (x_1^2+y_1^2) + \alpha_2^2\cdot (x_2^2+y_2^2)+2\alpha_1\alpha_2\cdot (x_1x_2+y_1y_2)\le$$

$$\le \alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2+2\alpha_1\alpha_2=1$$

Comment: The requirement is $(\alpha_1\cdot x_1 + \alpha_2\cdot x_2)^2 + (\alpha_1\cdot y_1 + \alpha_2\cdot y_2)^2 \leq 1$ not equal, the neq vector does not have to be on the unit circle, it has to be within. Then the last line becomes: $2\alpha_1\alpha_2 \cdot (x_1x_2 + y_1y_2)  -  2\alpha_1\alpha_2 \leq 0$, which is true?

Comment: Ops sorry I misunderstood the request, I fix it! Thanks

Comment: In transition from equation 3 to 4 it is assumed that $|r_{1,2}|^2 = 1$, which is not true in general, but I guess the proof is still valid since $|r_{1,2}|^2 = 1$ is the extreme case

Comment: @thorsan I try to revise completely in order to make it more clear.

Comment: @thorsan Now it should be fixed nad more clear.